# What should I update in my PHP setup when I change my MySQL databases to UTF-8 encoding?

Tags: php, mysql, character-encoding

I currently operate a website on a PHP 5 and MySQL backbone.  The MySQL databases uses `cp1252 West Europe ( latin1 )` encoding, and `latin1_swedish_cp` collation.

I'd like to switch the MySQL databases to `UTF-8` encoding and `utf8_general_ci`. I don't need help converting the content within MySQL as I'm processing that as it goes in and redoing all the content on the site.  Assume I'm doing that correctly for this conversation ( even though I'm probably not ).

I know there are settings in php.ini like `default_charset` that default to `iso-8859-1`.  I also know that many of PHP's string manipulation functions like `strlen()`, as well as regexes, will not work correctly if I'm dealing with strings that contain multi-byte UTF-8 characters, which I realize is not all characters in the UTF-8 set.

**What do I need to do to PHP server side and within my webapp to deal with UTF-8 coming out of my database?  What does it all do?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will have to set-up your DB connection with :

```
mysql_query("SET NAMES 'utf8'");
```

And then replace your "regular" string functions with those from the mbstring module :
http://php.net/manual/en/book.mbstring.php
like mb_strlen, mb_substr, etc.

As well as specify UTF-8 encoding where needed, for instance in the htmlentities function :

```
echo htmlentities($str, ENT_QUOTES, "UTF-8");
```

Comment: any thoughts on php settings within php.ini?

Comment: you should be good with what i listed here. php.ini's default_charset is used to define the Content-type HTTP header charset, which will be overriden by the <meta content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" http-equiv="content-type" /> tag of your HTML page, which i suppose you already set up (?)..

Comment: Seems like the http header is further up the chain and should be set in addition to the meta tag, or even instead of a meta tag defining content type on every page. Am I thinking of this incorrectly?

Answer (score 0):

See [this](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mb-convert-encoding.php) function.

Also, you should save all your files with utf-8 encoding (preferably without BOM).